# Dictionary TryGetValue out parameter

Tags: c#, dictionary

Does TryGetValue change input parameter?

when using TryGetValue, I tend to do:

```
Dictionary<int, long> myDic;
long lValue = -1;
long lTemp1;

if( myDic.TryGetValue(100, out lTemp1)){
    lValue = lTemp1;
}
```

should I write directly this way?

```
myDic.TryGetValue(nKeyToLookup, out lValue);
```

Comment: ... or reading the docs is often very useful https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.idictionary-2.trygetvalue?view=netframework-4.8 *When this method returns, the value associated with the specified key, if the key is found; otherwise, the default value for the type of the value parameter.*

Comment: The only thing you are doing by creating a separate temporary variable, is using up memory space.

Comment: Why not `if(myDic.TryGetValue(nKeyToLookup, out long lValue)`

Comment: You can actually just do `if (myDic.TryGetValue (100, out var lValue) { }` and `lValue` will get declared and properly initialized (either to `default(long)`, i.e.  `0L`, or to the correct value if it's found)

Comment: _"Does TryGetValue change input parameter?"_ -- I don't understand your question at all. If it _didn't_ change the input parameter's value, how in the world would `lTemp1` have the value you want to assign to `lValue`? This question makes zero sense.

Comment: Sorry for the vague meaning. I actually hope even if the lookup fails, the value parameter could remain unchanged. because sometimes I have already had initial value in the parameter (lValue = -1 in my example).

Comment: `out` should always change the output value, it's mandated by the compiler that it does. As such, no, it will not keep its original value if the key is not found in the dictionary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.idictionary-2.trygetvalue?view=netframework-4.8) states

> When this method returns, the value associated with the specified key, if the key is found; otherwise, the default value for the type of the value parameter.

the value will be changed.

If you want to shorten your code you can do this

```
Dictionary<int, long> myDic;

if( !myDic.TryGetValue(100, out var lValue))
{
    lValue = -1;
}
```

---

**Update**

You could write a custom `TryGetValue` extension method which accepts a `ref TValue value`

```
public static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static bool TryGetValue<TKey,TValue>( this IDictionary<TKey,TValue> dict, TKey key, ref TValue value )
    {
        var result = dict.TryGetValue( key, out var foundValue );
        if ( result )
            value = foundValue;
        return result;
    }
}
```

live working example at [.net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EnCoXG)

Comment: I got it. it means I have to do something to keep the initial value. because extra code is inevitable, I wish it be kept unchanged, otherwise it seems necessary after all to introduce another variable.

Comment: sure this might be the reasonable solution I think. because if there is possibility that no item could be looked up, why a value must be assigned.

Comment: @Chengting Because in C# you have to assign a value to an **out** parameter otherwise the code will not compile.

Comment: so I think maybe the original TryGetValue had better use ref instead of out. because expecting failure by using the "Try" function, I myself would have prepared another more meaningful default value other than a type's default value. and if TryGetValue finds nothing, it need not bother do the assignment.